# Poisson parameter equal to product of binomial parameters

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I'm wondering why the parameter $\lambda$ of a Poisson distribution ($Poisson(\lambda)$) is equal to the product between the parameters of a binomial distribution ($Bin(n, \, p)$):

$$
\lambda = n \, p
$$

Comment: Why would they be equal? Please provide the complete context.

Comment: Hello @StubbornAtom I'm studying a proof of the fact that the Poisson distribution is a limit of the binomial distribution when $n \to \infty$ and $p \to 0$. In the proof of my prof I read $\lambda = n \, p$ but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally speaking, the parameter of a Poisson random variable is not equal to the product of parameters of the Binomial. It is do it this way because Poisson distribution can be considered as an approximation to Binomial for $n$ big and $p$ small enough so that $\lambda = np$ be of moderate size. Indeed, it can be proven that if $X$ has binomial distribution $Bin(n,p)$, and $\lambda=np$ then
$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}\bigg(\frac{\lambda}{n}\bigg)^k\bigg(1 - \frac{\lambda}{n}\bigg)^{n-k}\to e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$$
when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Hello @TomKeen thank you very much for your clarification.